# partition by based on a condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[image]

Table has customer, purchase date, item information

Need to populate first purchase date of "Item B" by any customer in a new column as "Min Purchase Date"

Try:
select
Customer ,
Purchase date,
Item
min(purchase date) over (partition by customer_id) as Min Purchase date
from table
where item = 'B'

Result

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function with conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       min(case when item = 'B' then purchasedate end) over (partition by customer) 
from t;
```